# How do I keep this header responsive?

Tags: css

I have been given a mock-up design with a header that hass a curved image (similar to http://www.smartwebby.com/images/tutorials/fireworks/website_design_fireworks/pic_header_footer.gif or http://theme-fusion.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/curved-header.png). at the top. The thing is it has to be fluid & responsive. I like to conceptually figure things out somewhat before I start making them. Can someone help me how I would make this responsive. If I just make it 100% width its going to be extremely distorted at some points. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you guessed you can use width: 100% but then use media queries to serve a different image to different screen sizes such as:

```
header {
    width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
    header {
        background-image: url("/img/image-xs.png");
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
    header {
        background-image: url("/img/image-sm.png");
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
    header {
        background-image: url("/img/image-md.png");
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
    header {
        background-image: url("/img/image-lg.png");
    }
}
```

The multiple selection of images allows you to combat the pixelation that you are afraid of. By serving an image that fits the screen best at different break points, you will keep the image quality relatively good at all sizes.